# Testing Availability of External Data

Tags: testing, integration, system

In which level of testing,we should test for the data from an external source.

For eg:When there is AirLine Flight schedule has interact with Airport Traffic Control System.This can be identified in which level of testing.

Also,please provide me if there is any external resource that clearly defines the type of testing to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Some people call this integration testing as two or more systems integrate.